# How do I join the Bitcoin Core PR review club meetings on IRC?

Tags: bitcoincore-review, irc

I would like to learn about reviewing Bitcoin Core pull requests at the [Bitcoin Core PR review club](https://bitcoincore.reviews/your-first-meeting). How do I join the ##bitcoin-core-pr-reviews channel on IRC ([Libera.Chat](https://libera.chat/) network) and which IRC client do you recommend I install?

I can use the command line but I would prefer to maximize convenience and minimize setup time.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu, I like [weechat](https://weechat.org/).

On OSX I've used [Colloquy](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10526/colloquy) before but have recently upgraded to [Textual](https://www.codeux.com/textual/) which is not free -- unless you [build it from source :-)](https://github.com/Codeux-Software/Textual/#note-regarding-trial-mode).

There is even a [web interface](https://webchat.freenode.net/) for freenode, but I'm not sure if it requires authentication to join the channel.

Comment: Do you know any good IRC client for Android? I tried [AndroIRC](http://www.androirc.com/) but had issues connecting to freenode server using [Riseup](https://riseup.net/en) VPN and Tor. Can we have XMPP server for bitcoin-core instead of IRC? Also web interface doesn't require authentication. I have tried it. But unable to connect using VPN or Tor.

Comment: I don't know about android but I do have an iOS app called Mutter that works - I've joined review club from the subway!

Comment: This reddit post mentioned that app is not available anymore https://www.reddit.com/r/irc/comments/eha8yj/what_happened_to_mutter_for_ios/fchapyt/ but I found another app in replies https://palaverapp.com/ and it is partially open source as well

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin Core PR review club [site](https://bitcoincore.reviews/) links to this beginner's [guide](https://fedoramagazine.org/beginners-guide-irc/) to IRC.

There are more impressive IRC setups such as Pieter Wuille's [setup](https://twitter.com/pwuille/status/1171669782065795072?s=20).

> My setup is: juicessh on my phone, ssh into my VPS (non-tor), where I run irssi in screen, which connects via tor to freenode and other networks

But you said you wanted to minimize setup time. In that case I would recommend [Textual](https://www.codeux.com/textual/) on MacOS (as pinhead does in his answer). It isn't free, the license costs $7.99 at the time of writing (September 2020). There is a FAQ for using Textual [here](https://help.codeux.com/textual/Frequently-Asked-Questions.kb).

This will allow you to join the Bitcoin Core PR review club meetings but you won't be able to receive messages or view discussion that has happened on channels while you were offline. You would need to set up a bouncer on a virtual private server to do that (or refer to third party conversation [logs](http://www.erisian.com.au/meetbot/bitcoin-core-dev/)). For that I recommend [ZNC](https://wiki.znc.in/ZNC) but first get set up with a IRC client like Textual.

Further [discussion](https://twitter.com/dunxen/status/1440021676884905988?s=20) on terminal based IRC clients.